# conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, valgrind

I'm not too sure how to troubleshoot or understand what could be happening, any help would be appreciated and if there is any clarification needed I would be more than happy to provide, Thanks!

Comment: Whatever else, `char ran[4];` should be, say `char ran[100];` to give it headroom, and you must check the array index bounds of `i` and `k`.

Comment: Where does the string you're putting into `char ran[4];` end?  How would `atoi()` know?

Comment: You did not write a string terminator in `ran` required by `atoi`.

Comment: `while(line[i] != ',' && line[i] >= ' ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're constructing in `ran` doesn't have a terminating null byte, so `atoi` will read past the bytes you've written into the ones you haven't (and possibly past the end of the array), which is what valgrind is telling you.

You'll need to manually terminate the string after reading the characters.

```
while(line[i] != ',') {
     ran[k] = line[i];
     i = i + 1;
     k = k + 1;
}
ran[k] = 0;
```